# Query involving views and functions can't use index

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-performance

I have the following postgresql query (simplified for readability):

```
select *
from a_view
where a in (select * from a_function(a_input))
      and b in (select * from b_function(b_input));
```

this query performs unreasonably slow.

If I run both subqueries independently, they are pretty fast. If I run the query writing out outputs of subqueries, i.e.:

```
select *
from a_view
where a in (394990, 393762, 393748, 1)
      and b in (331142, 330946, 331228, 331325);
```

that is also pretty fast. I run `explain analyze` and realize in the original form above, the query cant utilize indexes and uses sequential scanning. Just to give more detail, the view (a_view) involves a big table (10+ million rows) and it is indexed on both (a,b) and (b).

Is there a way to help query utilize the indexes?

Comment: You could try putting the `select * from a_function(a_input)` into a CTE and see if that changes anything

Comment: Here is CTE version: `with a_temp as (select * from a_function(a_input)), b_temp as (select * from b_function(b_input)) select *
from a_view
where a in (select * from a_temp)
      and b in (select * from b_temp)`;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Would using `joins` instead of `in (..)` help?

Comment: Using joins did not help either.

Comment: I tried writing out the query instead of using the view, that did not help either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two issues:

1. By default any SRF function has `ROWS` clause on 1000 - so does the planner expect. It is false in your example. Try to set this attribute to a more appropriate value (e.g., 10 - too small might be bad too):

   ```
   postgres=# explain select * from xx();
   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                        QUERY PLAN                         │
   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
   │ Function Scan on xx  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   (1 row)
   ```
2. PLpgSQL function is a **blackbox** for the planner. The planner has much more information about predicates if you use just a list of constants as compared to you using a function. In this case, the planner have to use some default rules, those are probably too out for your case.

   ```
   postgres=# explain select * from xx where a in (10,20);
   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                     QUERY PLAN                     │
   ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
   │ Seq Scan on xx  (cost=0.00..170.00 rows=2 width=4) │
   │   Filter: (a = ANY ('{10,20}'::integer[]))         │
   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   (2 rows)

   postgres=# explain select * from xx where a in (select * from xx());
   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                    QUERY PLAN                                    │
   ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
   │ Hash Join  (cost=17.25..201.85 rows=5000 width=4)                                │
   │   Hash Cond: (xx.a = xx_1.xx)                                                    │
   │   ->  Seq Scan on xx  (cost=0.00..145.00 rows=10000 width=4)                     │
   │   ->  Hash  (cost=14.75..14.75 rows=200 width=4)                                 │
   │         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12.75..14.75 rows=200 width=4)                  │
   │               Group Key: xx_1.xx                                                 │
   │               ->  Function Scan on xx xx_1  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   (7 rows)
   ```

   I have two potentially same queries with pretty different plans and with probably with pretty different performances.

What can be solution:

1. don't do it - using plpgsql in critical places (mainly `WHERE` clause) in SQL query can have pretty negative effect.
2. You can rewrite your function to return `int[]` instead `SETOF int`. In this case the planner will use different rules and performance can be better.

   ```
   postgres=# explain select * from xx where a = any( xx2());
   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                      QUERY PLAN                      │
   ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
   │ Seq Scan on xx  (cost=0.00..2770.00 rows=11 width=4) │
   │   Filter: (a = ANY (xx2()))                          │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   (2 rows)
   ```
3. If the results of `a_function` and `b_function` don't depend on content `a` and `b`, then they can be evaluated before the query by setting the flag `IMMUTABLE` on these functions. Then the functions are evaluated in planning time and the result is used as the constants - and planner will have much more information. **Attention: if the prerequisite is false, then the result can be wrong**. Be careful.

   ```
   -- xx2 is IMMUTABLE now
   postgres=# explain select * from xx where a = any( xx2());
   ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                      QUERY PLAN                       │
   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
   │ Seq Scan on xx  (cost=0.00..182.50 rows=3 width=4)    │
   │   Filter: (a = ANY ('{30314,3783,70448}'::integer[])) │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   (2 rows)
   ```

Comment: Your suggested solution #3 was actually what I was after. I tried that first, to my disappointment it did not make any difference. I also did `DISCARD ALL` to get rid of all cached query plans.

Comment: @MMatt: I am not sure if it is working for clause '= IN (SELECT). The result must be a array, not a set.

Comment: @MMatt: good old trick :) It should be somewhere in list http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks

Comment: Also in your issue #1 you say "Try to set this attribute to more adequate value" How do I do that?

Comment: @MMatt: it is typo - should be `IN (SELECT FROM fx())`. Although it visually similar, the implementation is significantly different from `= ANY(fx())`.

Comment: @MMatt: `ALTER FUNCTION xxx(..) ROWS 10;

Comment: Unfortunately, setting function `ROWS` to 10 did not help either. I stick to using array returning functions and `IMMUTABLE`.